# Insert menu into theme location depending on user logged in/out status

Tags: functions, menus, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using the [Avada Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226) from Themeforest and I have set up 2 menus under *Appearances > Menu*:

- `menu-logged-in` which contains a parent item (My Account) and then several child items; and
- `menu-logged-out` which contains a single link to the `/my-account` page where users can log in or register.

My intention hereafter is to dynamically show the relevant menu in the Theme location called *"Top Navigation"* depending on whether the user is logged in or is anonymous.

I've added this code into my child theme's `function.php`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'top_navigation') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Log Out</a></li>';
        //$items .= wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu-logged-in', 'container' => '') );
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'top_navigation') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Now this does work, but I would prefer to be able to call a Wordpress menu into the location instead of hard-coding these into the function. In the block above I have commented **line 5** that helps me achieve this, but it then renders a pre-formatted HTML <UL> at the very top of the page, and not where I want it to go.

[image]

I would be grateful if someone could please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: If the `<UL>` is part of `$items` you could remove it in the function using `str_replace('<UL>','',$items);` Often the `<UL>` is opened in the template itself before the `<li>` s are supplied dynamically.

Comment: A regex way t get rid of the <UL> by "willshouse" on this page looks promising https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-the-div-and-ul-tags-from-wp_nav_menu-function and it is put in a usable function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out! I've amended my theme function as follows:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'top_navigation') {
        $items .= wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu-logged-in', 'container' => '', 'echo' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s') );
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'top_navigation') {
        $items .= wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu-logged-out', 'container' => '', 'echo' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s') );
    }
    return $items;
}
```

So now, just gives me the `<li>` items I need and rendered in the correct position. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue despite surfing the internet for two weeks but still unsuccessful. unable to solve login logout issue. if a user logged in still it shows login. i have also two menu in wordpress appearances; one having the log in link and other items and the second one with logout link and other items.
Added the same function in avada child theme function file, but not successful.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/254077)